# Structuring x & y function arguments that work as both a formula (y ~ x) and separately

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function that runs x and y variables through a logistic regression and then later uses just the x variables to create a decision tree. (There will be other arguments in between, but they're not really relevant.)

Here is an example:

```
  myfunction <- function(x.vars, y.var, dat, method) {
  if (method == 1) {
  lr1 <-
  glm(
  x.vars, y.var,
  data = dat,
  family = "binomial"
  )

  ## I then use these results to come up with "some.other.variable"

  tree1 <-
  rpart(
  some.other.variable ~ x.vars,
  data = dat
  )

  # plot tree
  library(rpart.plot)
  rpart.plot(tree1)
  }

  else{...}
}
```

When I try to run a vector of x variables through this function, I get this error:

Error in formula.default(eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]])) : invalid formula

I'm guessing that this error is due to the fact that rpart only takes the "formula" argument (versus plugging in the x & y variables separately) and that just passing a vector of variable names as I'm doing in `some.other.variable ~ x.vars` isn't the right way. I'm not sure how to force it into the right format, though.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by requiring the x variables to be a matrix or data frame and then creating a new data frame within the function. Then I wrote the formula as "y ~ ." to avoid having to figure out how to put a "+" in between each of the variables (though I suppose I could call on their locations in the new data frame). I also ended up using caret to build the tree. There are probably better ways of doing this, but it worked.

```
  myfunction <- function(x.vars, y.var, dat, method) {
  if (method == 1) {
  new.dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(y.var, x.vars))
  names(new.dat)[1] <- "y"
  lr1 <-
  glm(y ~ .,
  data = new.dat,
  family = "binomial"
  )

  ## I then use these results to come up with "some.other.variable"
  library(caret)
  tree1 <- train(x = x.vars, y = new.variable, method = "rpart", trControl = trControl)
  )

  # plot tree
  library(rpart.plot)
  rpart.plot(tree1)
  }

  else{...}
}
```